# Why maven-surefire-plugin doesn't run the testng.xml file in priority order?

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My pom.xml file doesn't run the test scripts in priority order. I have mentioned the priority for the classes like priority=0, 1 and so on. But it picks up the classes randomly form the package. It should run as per priority order. Which works fine through testng.xml trigger.

```
<build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: can you show your test file with priority order listed?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to execution environment is set to JRE not JDK .
So changing the workspace default to JRE to JDK solved the issue .
For JRE HOME I gave C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
[image]

Because to compile having JDK is a must .